# C++ code to generate random DAGs

Tags: c++

I wrote the following C++ code a while ago to generate random graphs for a project I was working on:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    // std::min_element, std::max_element
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>



#define NoOfNodes 30


struct GPU_data
{
    int number_Copies;
    int workItems;
    int workGroups;
    bool memory;
    double power_consumption;
    double execTime;
};


struct DAG_data
{
    int processid; //Node's ID
    int PEid; //Processor's ID to which node is assigned
    std::vector<GPU_data> Node_config;
    int precede;
    int follow; //nodes following this node
    int noOfCopies;
    double transData;
    double ExecTime;
    double powerDraw;
};

void CreateandAssignEdges(DAG_data Sample, int NoOfEdges)
{
    
    unsigned int i = 0;

    if (Sample.processid == 0)
    {
        //parent process- so there will be no edges
        Sample.precede = 0;
        Sample.follow = rand()% NoOfEdges + 1;
    }

    else if (Sample.processid == NoOfNodes - 1)
    {
        //sink process- so there will be no following edges
        Sample.follow = 0;
    }

    else
    {
        //which nodes will the edges connect to (Anywhere from among the following nodes, including the sink node)
        Sample.follow = (Sample.processid + 1) + (std::rand() % (29 - (Sample.processid) + 1));

        if (Sample.follow == 30)
        {
            Sample.follow -= 1;
        }
    }

}

DAG_data EdgeAssignment(DAG_data Sample, int NoOfEdges)
{

    unsigned int i = 0;

    if (Sample.processid == 0)
    {
        //parent process- so there will be no edges
        Sample.precede = 0;
        Sample.follow = rand() % NoOfEdges + 1;

        return Sample;
    }

    else if (Sample.processid == NoOfNodes - 1)
    {
        //sink process- so there will be no following edges
        Sample.follow = 0;

        return Sample;
    }

    else
    {
        //which nodes will the edges connect to (Anywhere from among the following nodes, including the sink node)
        Sample.follow = (Sample.processid + 1) + (std::rand() % (29 - (Sample.processid) + 1));

        return Sample;
    }

}


        //Sample->precede = rand() % NoOfEdges;
        //Sample->follow = rand() % NoOfEdges;

        ////Preceding and following edges of a node should not be the same.
        //while (Sample->precede > Sample->follow || Sample->precede == Sample->follow)
        //{
        //  //assign both edges again
        //  Sample->follow = rand() % NoOfEdges;
        //  Sample->precede = rand() % NoOfEdges;
        //}

    



void whenPEisGPU(DAG_data Sample, int processorID)
{
    GPU_data emptySet;
    int i = 0;
    int NoOfConfigs = rand() % 5;
    GPU_data* sub_tasks = &emptySet;
    while (i != NoOfConfigs)
    {
        sub_tasks->memory = rand() % 1;
        sub_tasks->number_Copies = rand() % 3;
        sub_tasks->workGroups = rand() % 10 +1;
        sub_tasks->workItems = rand() % (sub_tasks->workGroups * 2) + 1;
        sub_tasks->power_consumption = rand() % 250;
        sub_tasks->execTime = rand() % (int)(Sample.ExecTime / 2);
        Sample.Node_config.push_back(*sub_tasks);
        i++;
    }
}

void PESpecificParameters(DAG_data Sample, int processorID)
{
    if (processorID == 0)
    {
        Sample.ExecTime = rand() % 100;
        Sample.powerDraw = 0.0;
        Sample.noOfCopies = 0;

    }
    else if (processorID == 1)
    {
        Sample.PEid = processorID;
        //whenPEisGPU(Sample, processorID);
        int i = 0;
        int NoOfConfigs = rand() % 5;
        GPU_data sub_tasks;
        while (i != NoOfConfigs)
        {
            sub_tasks.memory = rand() % 1;
            sub_tasks.number_Copies = rand() % 3+1;
            sub_tasks.workGroups = rand() % 10 + 1;
            sub_tasks.workItems = rand() % (sub_tasks.workGroups * 2) + 1;
            sub_tasks.power_consumption = rand() % 250;
            sub_tasks.execTime = rand() % (int)(Sample.ExecTime / 2);
            Sample.Node_config.push_back(sub_tasks);
            i++;
        }

    }

}

DAG_data PEParameters(DAG_data Sample, int processorID)
{
    if (processorID == 0)
    {
        Sample.ExecTime = rand() % 100;
        Sample.powerDraw = 0.0;
        Sample.noOfCopies = 0;

        return Sample;

    }
    else if (processorID == 1)
    {
        Sample.PEid = processorID;
        //whenPEisGPU(Sample, processorID);
        int i = 0;
        int NoOfConfigs = rand() % 5;
        GPU_data sub_tasks;
        while (i != NoOfConfigs)
        {
            sub_tasks.memory = rand() % 1;
            sub_tasks.number_Copies = rand() % 3 + 1;
            sub_tasks.workGroups = rand() % 10 + 1;
            sub_tasks.workItems = rand() % (sub_tasks.workGroups * 2) + 1;
            sub_tasks.power_consumption = rand() % 250;
            sub_tasks.execTime = rand() % (int)(Sample.ExecTime / 2) + 1;
            Sample.Node_config.push_back(sub_tasks);
            i++;
        }

        return Sample;

    }

}

void generateEdges(std::vector<DAG_data> &myTaskGraph)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;

    while (i != myTaskGraph.size())
    {
        for (unsigned int j = (myTaskGraph[i].processid)+1; j < myTaskGraph.size(); j++)
        {
            if (myTaskGraph[i].follow == 30)
            {
                myTaskGraph[i].follow -= 1;
            }
            //create an edge between the current node and any of its following nodes according to the following random number 
            if (rand() % 100 < 30)
            {
                myTaskGraph[i].follow = j;              
                break;
            }           
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
        
    DAG_data emptyDAG;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    std::ofstream myFile;


    std::vector<DAG_data> All_DAGs;

    while (i != NoOfNodes)
    {
        DAG_data DAG1;

        DAG1.processid = i;
        DAG1.transData = i + 1;
        DAG1.PEid = 0;

        DAG1= PEParameters(DAG1, DAG1.PEid);
        DAG1= EdgeAssignment(DAG1, 10);

        All_DAGs.push_back(DAG1);
        //DAG1.Node_config.clear();

        i++;
    }

    generateEdges(All_DAGs);

    for (int h = 0; h < All_DAGs.size(); h++)
    {
        if (h % 2 != 0)
        {
            DAG_data forNewPE =PEParameters(All_DAGs[h], 1);

            All_DAGs.push_back(forNewPE);
            All_DAGs[h].Node_config.clear();
            if (All_DAGs[h].processid ==29)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    
    }

    myFile.open("TG_Data_30NewEdges.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < All_DAGs.size(); i++)
    {
        myFile << "Node id: " << All_DAGs[i].processid << std::endl;
        myFile << "Following Edge: " << All_DAGs[i].follow << std::endl;
        myFile << "Transfer Data: " << All_DAGs[i].transData << std::endl;
        myFile << "Node PE: " << All_DAGs[i].PEid << std::endl;
        if (All_DAGs[i].PEid == 0)
        {
            myFile << "Execution time: " << All_DAGs[i].ExecTime << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            myFile << "-------------------------------" << std::endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < All_DAGs[i].Node_config.size(); j++)
            {
                myFile << "Execution time: " << All_DAGs[i].Node_config[j].execTime << std::endl;
                myFile << "Copies: " << All_DAGs[i].Node_config[j].number_Copies << std::endl;
                myFile << "Memory: " << All_DAGs[i].Node_config[j].memory << std::endl;
                myFile << "Work-Items: " << All_DAGs[i].Node_config[j].workItems << std::endl;
                myFile << "Work-Groups: " << All_DAGs[i].Node_config[j].workGroups << std::endl;
                myFile << "Power: " << All_DAGs[i].Node_config[j].power_consumption << std::endl;   
                myFile << "++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        myFile << "=================" << std::endl;
    }
    
    myFile.close();

    std::cout << "DONE NOW." << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

}
```

The code fulfilled its objective for me but there is a lot of room for improvement for this code. Please advise how this code can be rewritten to better adhere to the desired C++ practices.

Comment: What is a DAG? I read the question and all answers, but it is still unclear.

Comment: @Aganju DAG stands for [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Important errors:

- your random isn't random (seed it)
- your random isn't uniform (use uniform distributions rather than just taking
  the modulus, which will skew the distribution)
- `precede` is often uninitialized; `NoOfConfigs` is often uninitialized, and never used?
- The last loop before writing the output file **modifies the collection while iterating**:

  ```
   for (size_t h = 0; h < nodes.size(); h++) {
       // ...
       nodes.push_back(forNewPE);
  ```

  This is an anti-pattern. You only just get away with it because of

  ```
       if (nodes[h].processid == 29) { break; }
  ```

  which of course suffers from magic numbers, and could easily have been put
  in the loop condition instead:

  ```
   for (size_t h = 0; h < NoOfNodes; ++h) {
  ```
- `void PESpecificParameters(DAG_data Sample, int processorID)` is not used.

  When used, it will never have any effect (because it has netiher return
  values nor holds references to anything outside)
- Same with `whenPEisGPU`
- After removing duplicate code, it looks like `PEParameters` was identical to `PESpecificParameters` (see below)
- Likewise `CreateandAssignEdges` was unused and seems to be duplicating `EdgeAssignment`?

Major notes:

- Naming! `DAG_Data` means next to nothing. Your graph model represents
  *something* in real life. The fact that it is a DAG is like calling
  variables "textstring" instead of "FirstName" and "ZipCode"
- Extract some functions. Use them to

  - separate responsibilities,
  - levels of abstraction
  - reduce duplication
- Optionally group related functions with their data into classes (see "BONUS" section below)

---

Here comes a blow by blow of things I addressed:

1. Use warnings (-Wall -Wextra -pedantic at minimum) and swat them:

   ```
   test.cpp:43:18: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
      43 |     unsigned int i = 0;
   test.cpp:74:18: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
      74 |     unsigned int i = 0;
   test.cpp:119:39: warning: unused parameter ‘processorID’ [-Wunused-parameter]
     119 | void whenPEisGPU(DAG_data Sample, int processorID)
   test.cpp:259:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<DAG_data>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
     259 |     for (int h = 0; h < All_DAGs.size(); h++)
   test.cpp:277:23: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<DAG_data>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
     277 |     for (int i = 0; i < All_DAGs.size(); i++)
   test.cpp:290:31: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘std::vector<GPU_data>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
     290 |             for (int j = 0; j < All_DAGs[i].Node_config.size(); j++)
   test.cpp:204:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
     204 | }
   ```

   Changes:

   ```
   CreateandAssignEdges:
   -    unsigned int i = 0;

   EdgeAssignment:
   -    unsigned int i = 0;

   -void whenPEisGPU(DAG_data Sample, int processorID)
   +void whenPEisGPU(DAG_data Sample, int /*processorID*/)

   PEParameters:
   +    throw std::range_error("processorID");

   -    for (int h = 0; h < All_DAGs.size(); h++)
   +    for (size_t h = 0; h < All_DAGs.size(); h++)

   -    for (int i = 0; i < All_DAGs.size(); i++)
   +    for (size_t i = 0; i < All_DAGs.size(); i++)

   -            for (int j = 0; j < All_DAGs[i].Node_config.size(); j++)
   +            for (size_t j = 0; j < All_DAGs[i].Node_config.size(); j++)
   ```
2. Running modernize/readability check shows a lot of magic number warning and some easy improvements:

   ```
   clang-apply-replacements version 9.0.0
   clang-tidy-9 -header-filter=.* -checks=-*,readability-*,modernize-*,-modernize-use-trailing-return-type -export-fixes /tmp/tmp6CfbSr/tmpYGk6CX.yaml -p=/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:59:66: warning: 29 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           Sample.follow = (Sample.processid + 1) + (std::rand() % (29 - (Sample.processid) + 1));
                                                                    ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:61:30: warning: 30 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           if (Sample.follow == 30)
                                ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:81:5: warning: do not use 'else' after 'return' [readability-else-after-return]
       else if (Sample.processid == NoOfNodes - 1)
       ^~~~~
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:92:66: warning: 29 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           Sample.follow = (Sample.processid + 1) + (std::rand() % (29 - (Sample.processid) + 1));
                                                                    ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:119:32: warning: 5 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
       int NoOfConfigs = rand() % 5;
                                  ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:123:29: warning: implicit conversion 'int' -> bool [readability-implicit-bool-conversion]
           sub_tasks->memory = rand() % 1;
                               ^
                               ((        ) != 0)
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:125:42: warning: 10 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           sub_tasks->workGroups = rand() % 10 +1;
                                            ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:127:49: warning: 250 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           sub_tasks->power_consumption = rand() % 250;
                                                   ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:138:36: warning: 100 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           Sample.ExecTime = rand() % 100;
                                      ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:148:36: warning: 5 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           int NoOfConfigs = rand() % 5;
                                      ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:152:32: warning: implicit conversion 'int' -> bool [readability-implicit-bool-conversion]
               sub_tasks.memory = rand() % 1;
                                  ^
                                  ((        ) != 0)
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:154:45: warning: 10 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
               sub_tasks.workGroups = rand() % 10 + 1;
                                               ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:156:52: warning: 250 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
               sub_tasks.power_consumption = rand() % 250;
                                                      ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:170:36: warning: 100 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           Sample.ExecTime = rand() % 100;
                                      ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:177:5: warning: do not use 'else' after 'return' [readability-else-after-return]
       else if (processorID == 1)
       ^~~~~
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:182:36: warning: 5 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           int NoOfConfigs = rand() % 5;
                                      ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:186:32: warning: implicit conversion 'int' -> bool [readability-implicit-bool-conversion]
               sub_tasks.memory = rand() % 1;
                                  ^
                                  ((        ) != 0)
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:188:45: warning: 10 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
               sub_tasks.workGroups = rand() % 10 + 1;
                                               ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:190:52: warning: 250 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
               sub_tasks.power_consumption = rand() % 250;
                                                      ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:211:42: warning: 30 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
               if (myTaskGraph[i].follow == 30)
                                            ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:216:26: warning: 100 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
               if (rand() % 100 < 30)
                            ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:216:32: warning: 30 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
               if (rand() % 100 < 30)
                                  ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:246:36: warning: 10 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
           DAG1= EdgeAssignment(DAG1, 10);
                                      ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:264:41: warning: 29 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]
               if (All_DAGs[h].processid ==29)
                                           ^
   /home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/test.cpp:274:5: warning: use range-based for loop instead [modernize-loop-convert]
       for (size_t i = 0; i < All_DAGs.size(); i++)
       ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           (auto & All_DAG : All_DAGs)
   7510 warnings generated.
   Suppressed 7485 warnings (7485 in non-user code).
   Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers. Use -system-headers to display errors from system headers as well.
   Applying fixes ...
   ```

   At least take the ranged-for loop immediately:

   ```
   for (auto& DAG : All_DAGs)
   {
       myFile << "Node id: "        << DAG.processid << std::endl;
       myFile << "Following Edge: " << DAG.follow    << std::endl;
       myFile << "Transfer Data: "  << DAG.transData << std::endl;
       myFile << "Node PE: "        << DAG.PEid      << std::endl;
       if (DAG.PEid == 0)
       {
           myFile << "Execution time: " << DAG.ExecTime << std::endl;
       }
       else
       {
           myFile << "-------------------------------" << std::endl;
           for (auto& cfg : DAG.Node_config)
           {
               myFile << "Execution time: " << cfg.execTime          << std::endl;
               myFile << "Copies: "         << cfg.number_Copies     << std::endl;
               myFile << "Memory: "         << cfg.memory            << std::endl;
               myFile << "Work-Items: "     << cfg.workItems         << std::endl;
               myFile << "Work-Groups: "    << cfg.workGroups        << std::endl;
               myFile << "Power: "          << cfg.power_consumption << std::endl;
               myFile << "++++++++++++++++++" << std::endl;
           }
       }
       myFile << "=================" << std::endl;
   }
   ```
3. Don't unnecessarily separate initialization from declaration.

   ```
   std::ofstream myFile;
   // 40 lines...
   myFile.open("TG_Data_30NewEdges.txt");
   ```

   Don't unnecessarily manually resource manage:

   ```
   myFile.close();
   ```

   C++'s RAII pattern means the file will always be closed.

   ```
   {
       std::ofstream output("TG_Data_30NewEdges.txt");

       for (auto& DAG : All_DAGs)
       {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```

   Note I also renamed `myFile` to something more descriptive.
4. Time to extract some functions for the above:

   ```
   std::ofstream output("TG_Data_30NewEdges.txt");
   writeReport(output, All_DAGs);
   ```

   And then somewhere else:

   ```
   using DAGs = std::vector<DAG_data>;

   void writeReport(std::ostream& output, DAGs const& graphs) {
       for (auto& g : graphs) {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
5. De-mystify loops

   ```
   unsigned int i = 0;
   while (i != myTaskGraph.size()) {
       // ...
       i++;
   }
   ```

   Is conventionally written as

   ```
   for (size_t i = 0; i < myTaskGraph.size(); ++i) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Or, ever since c++0x:

   ```
   for (Node& node : myTaskGraph) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
6. Likewise the loops that build containers should probably read more like:

   ```
   Nodes nodes(NoOfNodes);

   size_t i = 0;
   for (auto& current : nodes) {
       current.processid = i;
       current.transData = i + 1;
       current.PEid = 0;

       i++;

       current = PEParameters(current, current.PEid);
       current = EdgeAssignment(current, 10);
   }
   ```

   And

   ```
   void whenPEisGPU(Node& node, int /*processorID*/)
   {
       int NoOfConfigs = rand() % 5;
       node.Node_config.assign(NoOfConfigs, {});

       for (auto& sub_task : node.Node_config) {
           sub_task.memory            = ((rand() % 1) != 0);
           sub_task.number_Copies     = rand() % 3;
           sub_task.workGroups        = rand() % 10 +1;
           sub_task.workItems         = rand() % (sub_task.workGroups * 2) + 1;
           sub_task.power_consumption = rand() % 250;
           sub_task.execTime          = rand() % (int)(node.ExecTime / 2);
       }
   }
   ```

   etc.

   > I'd probably write them as `std::generate_n` calls in real life, but
   > maybe we'll naturally arrive there, later below
7. Naming. Somewhere halfway the code, suddenly we get a glimpse of what we're really dealing with:

   ```
   void generateEdges(std::vector<DAG_data> &myTaskGraph)
   ```

   So, I guess we could name `DAG_data` `Node` or `Task` (or even `TaskNode`?).

   Likewise, we get subtle hints here:

   ```
   if (Sample.processid == 0) {
       //parent process- so there will be no edges
   ```

   and

   ```
   else if (node.processid == NoOfNodes - 1) {
       // sink process- so there will be no following edges
   ```

   > Side Note: you use `parent` as if it means "no edges". Which is
   > demonstratively inaccurate, because you immediately **do** set a follower
   > edge. What you seem to mean is the "parent without a parent", which in a
   > DAG is usually known as a "root". Note also, that if you have a DAG with
   > only 1 root, why not call it a Tree?
   >
   > // file under: naming is important

   So, we should make that more readable:

   ```
   using ProcessID = int;
   static constexpr size_t NoOfNodes = 30;
   static constexpr ProcessID RootNodeId = 0;
   static constexpr ProcessID SinkNodeId = NoOfNodes - 1;

   // ...
   static bool constexpr IsSink(ProcessID id) { return SinkNodeId == id; }
   static bool constexpr IsSink(Node const& node) { return IsSink(node.processid); }
   // etc?
   ```
8. In fact, maybe it's better to combine the whole thing:

   ```
   enum ProcessID : int {
       RootNodeId = 0,
       NoOfNodes  = 30,
       SinkNodeId = NoOfNodes -1,
   };
   ```

   This leads to a great reduction of all magic numbers ( `= 0` becomes `= RootNodeId` etc).

   However, it forces us to address the problem with the other "magic" assignements:

   ```
   node.follow = rand() % NoOfEdges + 1;
   node.follow =
       (node.processid + 1) + (std::rand() % (29 - (node.processid) + 1));
   ```

   I mean, we were going to address those anways (because, ugh and skewed random).
9. So, let's address random! You started out correctly:

   ```
   #include <random>
   ```

   but never used a thing from that [treasure trove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)!

   ```
   std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device{} () };
   ```

   Now we have our UniformRandomBitGenerator **and** we securely seeded it!

   Let's create some helper functions that will help us generate uniformly distributed numbers:

   Generate numbers up to and including max:

   ```
   auto gen_number(int max, bool includeZero = true) {
       using Dist  = std::uniform_int_distribution<>;
       using Param = Dist::param_type;
       static Dist dist;

       auto min = includeZero? 0:1;
       assert(max >= min);
       return dist(prng, Param(min, max));
   }
   ```

   Adding a short hand for [1, max] random sample:

   ```
   auto gen_positive(int max) {
       return gen_number(max, false);
   }
   ```

   Now, to generate ProcessID we need some conversions and we can assume some
   defaults for the range limits:

   ```
   ProcessID gen_follower(int from = FirstFollow, int to = NoOfNodes) {
       using T     = std::underlying_type_t<ProcessID>;
       using Dist  = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
       using Param = Dist::param_type;

       static Param full{static_cast<T>(FirstFollow), static_cast<T>(NoOfNodes)};
       static Dist dist(full);

       return static_cast<ProcessID>(dist(prng, Param(from, to)));
   }
   ```

   Now we can rephrase the expressions:

   ```
   // node.follow = rand() % NoOfEdges + 1;
   node.follow = gen_follower(FirstFollow, NoOfEdges);
   ```

   And

   ```
   // node.follow =
   //     (node.processid + 1) + (std::rand() % (29 - (node.processid) + 1));
   node.follow = gen_follower(node.processid+1);
   ```

   > Much simpler, type-safe and uniform!

   Now, there's some weird things about this.

   - Everywhere `follow` is implied to be from the `ProcessId` domain.
     However, the expression `gen_follower(FirstFollow, NoOfEdges)` uses
     `NoOfEdges` instead of `NoOfNodes`?! `NoOfEdges` is also just hardcoded
     at `10` for the one call to `EdgeAssignment`.

     Are you sure you meant to "arbitrarily" limit follower nodes for the
     Root Node to `[1..10]` regardless of `NoOfNodes`?

     > Since subsequent followers are always taken "down-stream" I can
     > **guess** that you wanted to pick from a "first 10" partition only to
     > increase the likelihood of subtasks to beget "grand children". If so,
     > the name `NoOfEdges` is completely misleading, and could be something
     > like `FirstGenerationNodes`?)
   - There are ***two*** locations where the result of these expressions is being corrected:

     ```
      if (myTaskGraph[i].follow == 30) {
          myTaskGraph[i].follow -= 1;
      }

      if (Sample.follow == 30) {
          Sample.follow -= 1;
      }
     ```

     If that's the desired range, simply fix your expressions!

     As written it makes the code hard to understand, spreads responsibility
     across functions (which invites bugs) and also further skews the
     distribution: `29` is now a much more likely edge target.

     I chose to fix the expression to match the implied intent from this other comment:

     ```
     // which nodes will the edges connect to (Anywhere from among the
     // following nodes, including the sink node)
     node.follow = gen_follower(node.processid+1, SinkNodeId);
     ```
10. Code duplication. The generation of subtasks (`node.Node_config`) is
    duplicated, with some spurious differences that might be bugs, but could be
    intentional?

    E.g.:

    ```
    sub_task.number_Copies = rand() % 3 + 1;
    ```

    One of three copies omit `+1` which is likely a bug.

    In similar fashion we see one copy of

    ```
    sub_task.execTime = rand() % static_cast<int>(node.ExecTime / 2);
    ```

    that adds an `+1`. Likely this avoids zero `execTime`, and is a code smell that this too should have been a strong-typed, uniform real random distribution.

    > It's hard to guess what you actually want `execTime` to mean. If you mean
    > it to be such that parent node's execTime always totals the sum of their
    > subtasks, that is much easier to express with some business logic, rather
    > than having the data redundant in your datastructure and add undocumented
    > invariants (which, again, invite bugs).
    >
    > For fun, I added how I'd write the distribution on a whim:
    >
    > ```
    >     void distributeExecTime(Node& node) {
    >         std::vector<double> weights;
    >         std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist;
    >         std::generate_n(
    >             back_inserter(weights),
    >             node.Node_config.size(),
    >             [&dist] { return dist(prng); });
    >
    >         auto total_w = std::accumulate(begin(weights), end(weights), 0.);
    >
    >         for (size_t i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i) {
    >             node.Node_config[i].execTime = (weights[i]/total_w) * node.ExecTime;
    >         }
    >     }
    > ```
11. For total power draw there seems to be similar things going on. Perhaps you can replace powerDraw with a function:

    ```
    double powerDraw() const {
        return std::accumulate(begin(Node_config), end(Node_config), 0.);
    };
    ```

### BONUS

Going over the edge, we can envision a world where the generating is "automatic", as is the reporting:

- Consider moving generation into constructors:

  ```
   struct GPU_data {
       int number_Copies        = gen_positive(3);
       int workGroups           = gen_positive(10); // order is important!
       int workItems            = gen_positive(workGroups * 2);
       bool memory              = odds(50);
       double power_consumption = gen_real(249);
       double execTime          = 0; // see distributeExecTime
   };
  ```

  > Note
  >
  > - we're using C++11 NSMI to generate the default constructor for us

  ```
   struct Node {
       enum Type { CPUNode, GPUNode };

       Type      PEid;      // Processor's ID to which node is assigned
       ProcessID processid; // Node's ID
       Configs   sub_tasks;
       ProcessID follow    = RootNodeId; // nodes following this node
       double    transData = 0;
       double    ExecTime  = 0;

       explicit Node(int id, int NoOfEdges = 10)
         : PEid(CPUNode),
           processid(ProcessID(id)),
           transData(id + 1)
       {
           PEParameters();
           EdgeAssignment(NoOfEdges);
       }

       explicit Node(Node const& node)
        : PEid(GPUNode),
          processid(node.processid),
          sub_tasks(),
          follow(node.follow),
          transData(node.transData),
          ExecTime(node.ExecTime)
       {
           PEParameters();
       }

       double powerDraw() const;
       bool isGPU() const { return PEid == GPUNode; }

     private:
       void PEParameters();
       void EdgeAssignment(int NoOfEdges);
       void distributeExecTime();
   };
  ```

  Now, `Node` can group with it's manipulating functions:

  > - This sort of assumes the types are not already in use elsewhere. In case
  >   that's not the case, we can sub-class the types and benefit from object
  >   slicing to convert back to its base class.
  > - Note as well that several places in the code (PEParameters, output and
  >   EdgeAssignment) switch behaviour on PEid which apparently has only two
  >   valid values. I've changed that to be an enum reflecting that fact:
  >
  >   ```
  >   enum Type { CPUNode, GPUNode };
  >   Type      PEid;      // Processor's ID to which node is assigned
  >   ```
  >
  >   As an exercise for the reader, it might make sense to change `Node` to some kind of polymorphic type instead of switching all the time:
  >
  >   ```
  >   using Node = std::variant<CPUNode, GPUNode>;
  >   ```
  >
  >   Or using virtual types (inheritance).

### Demo Listing(s)

All revisison are here in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/sehe/32c07118031a049042bd9fb469355caf/revisions

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a4e46b62b35e6a0d)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>    // std::min_element, std::max_element
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

namespace {
    static std::mt19937 prng { std::random_device{} () };

    enum ProcessID : int {
        RootNodeId /*= 0 */,
        NoOfNodes    = 30,

        FirstFollow  = RootNodeId +1,
        SinkNodeId   = NoOfNodes -1,
    };

    auto gen_number(int max, bool includeZero = true) {
        using Dist  = std::uniform_int_distribution<>;
        using Param = Dist::param_type;
        static Dist dist;

        auto min = includeZero? 0:1;
        assert(max >= min);
        return dist(prng, Param(min, max));
    }

    auto gen_positive(int max) {
        return gen_number(max, false);
    }

    ProcessID gen_follower(int from = FirstFollow, int to = NoOfNodes) {
        using T     = std::underlying_type_t<ProcessID>;
        using Dist  = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
        using Param = Dist::param_type;

        static Param full{static_cast<T>(FirstFollow), static_cast<T>(NoOfNodes)};
        static Dist dist(full);

        return static_cast<ProcessID>(dist(prng, Param(from, to)));
    }

    bool odds(int percentage) {
        if (percentage == 100)
            return true;
        assert(percentage > 0 && percentage < 100);
        return std::discrete_distribution<bool>(percentage, 100-percentage)(prng);
    }

    double gen_real(double mean = 100.0, double stddev = 0) {
        if (stddev == 0)
            stddev = mean/4;
        assert(stddev>0);
        return std::normal_distribution(mean, stddev)(prng);
    }
}

struct GPU_data {
    int number_Copies        = gen_positive(3);
    int workGroups           = gen_positive(10); // order is important!
    int workItems            = gen_positive(workGroups * 2);
    bool memory              = odds(50);
    double power_consumption = gen_real(249);
    double execTime          = 0; // see distributeExecTime
};

using Configs = std::vector<GPU_data>;

struct Node {
    enum Type { CPUNode, GPUNode };

    Type      PEid;      // Processor's ID to which node is assigned
    ProcessID processid; // Node's      ID
    Configs   sub_tasks;
    ProcessID follow    = RootNodeId; // nodes following this node
    double    transData = 0;
    double    ExecTime  = 0;

    explicit Node(int id, int NoOfEdges = 10)
      : PEid(CPUNode),
        processid(ProcessID(id)),
        transData(id + 1)
    {
        PEParameters();
        EdgeAssignment(NoOfEdges);
    }

    explicit Node(Node const& node)
     : PEid(GPUNode),
       processid(node.processid),
       sub_tasks(),
       follow(node.follow),
       transData(node.transData),
       ExecTime(node.ExecTime)
    {
        PEParameters();
    }

    double powerDraw() const {
        double total = 0;
        for (auto& sub: sub_tasks) {
            total += sub.power_consumption;
        }
        return total;
    };

    bool isGPU() const { return PEid == GPUNode; }

  private:
    void PEParameters() {
        switch(PEid) {
          case CPUNode:
            ExecTime = gen_real(100.0);
            break;
          case GPUNode:
            sub_tasks.resize(gen_number(5));
            distributeExecTime();
            break;
          default:
            throw std::range_error("PEid");
        }
    }

    void EdgeAssignment(int NoOfEdges) {
        if (processid == RootNodeId) {
            // parent process- so there will be no edges
            follow  = gen_follower(FirstFollow, NoOfEdges);
        }
        else if (processid == SinkNodeId) {
            // sink process- so there will be no following edges
            follow = RootNodeId;
        }
        else {
            // which nodes will the edges connect to (Anywhere from among the
            // following nodes, including the sink node)
            follow = gen_follower(processid+1, SinkNodeId);
        }
    }

    void distributeExecTime() {
        std::vector<double> weights;
        std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist;
        std::generate_n(
            back_inserter(weights),
            sub_tasks.size(),
            [&dist] { return dist(prng); });

        auto total_w = std::accumulate(begin(weights), end(weights), 0.);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < weights.size(); ++i) {
            sub_tasks[i].execTime = (weights[i]/total_w) * ExecTime;
        }
    }
};

using Nodes = std::vector<Node>;

void generateEdges(Nodes& nodes) {
    for (Node& node : nodes) {
        // Create an edges to following nodes given 30% odds
        for (size_t j = node.processid+1; j < nodes.size(); j++) {
            if (odds(30)) {
                node.follow = static_cast<ProcessID>(j);              
                break;
            }           
        }
    }
}

static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node const& n);

int main() {
    Nodes nodes;
    for (auto id = 0; id < NoOfNodes; ++id) {
        nodes.emplace_back(id);
    }

    generateEdges(nodes);

    for (size_t h = 0; h < NoOfNodes; h++) {
        if (h % 2 == 0)
            continue;

        nodes.emplace_back(nodes[h]);
        nodes[h].sub_tasks.clear();
    }

    std::ofstream output("TG_Data_30NewEdges.txt");
    for (auto& n : nodes) {
        output << n << "=================\n";
    }

    std::cout << "DONE" << std::endl;
}

static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, GPU_data const& cfg) {
    return os 
        << "Execution time: " << cfg.execTime          << "\n"
        << "Copies: "         << cfg.number_Copies     << "\n"
        << "Memory: "         << cfg.memory            << "\n"
        << "Work-Items: "     << cfg.workItems         << "\n"
        << "Work-Groups: "    << cfg.workGroups        << "\n"
        << "Power: "          << cfg.power_consumption << "\n";
}

static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Node const& n) {
    os << "Node id: "        << n.processid   << "\n"
       << "Following Edge: " << n.follow      << "\n"
       << "Transfer Data: "  << n.transData   << "\n"
       << "Node powerDraw: " << n.powerDraw() << "\n"
       << "Node PE: "        << n.PEid        << "\n";

    if (n.isGPU()) {
        os << "-------------------------------\n";
        for (auto& cfg : n.sub_tasks) {
            os << cfg << "++++++++++++++++++\n";
        }
    } else {
        os << "Execution time: " << n.ExecTime << "\n";
    }
    return os;
}
```

Prints, e.g.

```
DONE
```

And generates TG_Data_30NewEdges.txt:

```
Node id: 0
Following Edge: 1
Transfer Data: 1
Node powerDraw: 1020.61
Node PE: 1
-------------------------------
Execution time: 12.2428
Copies: 1
Memory: 1
Work-Items: 10
Work-Groups: 9
Power: 229.989
++++++++++++++++++
Execution time: 39.2756
Copies: 1

// ...
// 825 lines snipped
// ...

Copies: 3
Memory: 1
Work-Items: 3
Work-Groups: 9
Power: 235.512
++++++++++++++++++
=================
```

Comment: Added all revisison are here in a Gist: https://gist.github.com/sehe/32c07118031a049042bd9fb469355caf/revisions

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to my request to review my code and thank you again for posting such a comprehensive review. The "new" code has many C++ concepts I did not know about earlier. I can enhance my C++ knowledge considerably just by reading this review :)

Comment: What's happening?!  A month later I suddenly get a stream of upvotes on this answer :) Not complaining, just confused

Comment: It's on the c++ subreddit 

Comment: I just have to say how impressed I am at the level of detail and positive advice you've given here, it's really impressive. I can only imagine how much time it took you. Really wholesome and generous. Kudos

Comment: @sehe The code in the question more or less represents the height of my C++ knowledge. I am going to read [A Tour of C++](https://www.amazon.ca/Tour-C-2nd-Bjarne-Stroustrup/dp/0134997832) to enhance my knowledge and understanding of C++. Do you have any further suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #define NoOfNodes 30
> ```

I think it would be better to use a `static constexpr` here rather than a preprocessor macro.

> ```
>     //which nodes will the edges connect to (Anywhere from among the following nodes, including the sink node)
>     Sample.follow = (Sample.processid + 1) + (std::rand() % (29 - (Sample.processid) + 1));
>
>     if (Sample.follow == 30)
>     {
>         Sample.follow -= 1;
>     }
> ```

Where do the constants `29` and `30` come from?  Should they be derived from `NoOfNodes` instead?

It may be better to use the C++ `<random>` library than `std::rand()`.

`CreateandAssignEdges()` and `EdgeAssignment()` are very similar - I think the duplication can be greatly reduced.

> ```
>    //Sample->precede = rand() % NoOfEdges;
>     //Sample->follow = rand() % NoOfEdges;
>
>     ////Preceding and following edges of a node should not be the same.
>     //while (Sample->precede > Sample->follow || Sample->precede == Sample->follow)
>     //{
>     //  //assign both edges again
>     //  Sample->follow = rand() % NoOfEdges;
>     //  Sample->precede = rand() % NoOfEdges;
>     //}
> ```

Chunks of commented-out code like this often become a problem, becoming out of date and inconsistent as the surrounding code changes.  Either remove it, or find a way to ensure it gets compiled and unit-tested with the rest of the code.

> ```
>     myFile << "Node id: " << All_DAGs[i].processid << std::endl;
>     myFile << "Following Edge: " << All_DAGs[i].follow << std::endl;
>     myFile << "Transfer Data: " << All_DAGs[i].transData << std::endl;
>     myFile << "Node PE: " << All_DAGs[i].PEid << std::endl;
> ```

There's no real need to flush `myFile` each statement - prefer `'\n'` to `std::endl` for all of these (and most/all of the remaining uses).

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Do you think it would be better to split my code into classes?

Comment: _Where do the constants `29` and `30` come from? Should they be derived from `NoOfNodes` instead?_ Yes. Those values should be coming from `NoOfNodes`.